# Is SHA-1 length always 40 symbols?

Tags: node.js, hash, hex, sha1

I'm using `crypto` lib to creating SHA1 hash:

```
crypto.createHash('sha1').update(hashValue).digest('hex')
```

The typical result is `a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d`. This hash has length of 40 characters. So does result always have length 40?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> SHA-1 produces a 160-bit (20-byte) hash value known as a message
>   digest. A SHA-1 hash value is typically rendered as a hexadecimal
>   number, 40 digits long.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Comment: How is a literal copy-paste from wikipedia getting that many upvotes?

Comment: Because it answers the question? I mean if it already has a clear answer elsewhere, why reinvent the qheel?